# How to connect Mongodb Admin GUI to Cloud Foundry?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cloud-foundry, mongovue

I am looking a way to browse my Cloud Foundry Mongodb services. Look like there are two options:

1. Tunneling to a Cloud Foundry Service with Caldecott http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/caldecott.html. I never tried this but I guess it may work.
2. My question is this: **Is it possible to connect directly into Cloud Foundry from Mongodb Admin GUI such as mViewer or Mongovue**? But if so, how do I know the username/password in `process.env.VCAP_SERVICES['mongodb-1.8'][0]['credentials']`?

https://github.com/Imaginea/mViewer

http://www.mongovue.com/2011/08/04/mongovue-connection-to-remote-server-over-ssh/

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a tunnel using Caldecott.

See http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/caldecott.html.

When you open the tunnel, it should provide you with either a command line client, or the credentials to use.

In case it does not, create a piece of code that returns a dump of `process.env.VCAP_SERVICES` when visit a certain url on your server.

Comment: FYI Opening the tunnel will give you the credentials, no need to query VCAP_SERVICES env variable.

Answer (score 1):

By using the GUI client you have to get a tunnel to the service. Once you open it in a CLI console the connection info will be generated and displayed, including the host address, usually 127.0.0.1, port number, username and password. You cannot connect using the values from VCAP_SERVICES if you try to do that from outside environment because these will be local values behind the CF router.